# Warning: I could not find the column named 'rowid'

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I use FMDB in my iOS project. But when I read ROWID with FMDB，the Xcode log "Warning: I could not find the column named 'rowid'."

```
...
 //Create database
 NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsPath   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookmarksDatabase.sqlite"];

    BOOL needCreateTable = ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [db open];
    if (needCreateTable) {

        [db executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE bookmarks (title TEXT ,url TEXT ,folderID INTEGER ,locationIndex INTEGER)"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self reloadBookmarkDatabase:db];

    }

        [db close];

   ...
   //Read database. Only "ROWID" column can't find.
FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM bookmarks ORDER BY locationIndex"];
    while([results next]) {
        BookmarkData *temp  = [[BookmarkData alloc] initWithID:[results intForColumn:@"ROWID"] title:[results stringForColumn:@"title"] url:[results stringForColumn:@"url"] folderID:[results intForColumn:@"folderID"] locationIndex:[results intForColumn:@"locationIndex"]];
        [self.bookmarkArray addObject:temp];

        NSLog(@"bookmark id:%d, title:%@, url:%@, folderID:%d, locationIndex:%d",temp.ID,temp.title,temp.url,temp.folderID,temp.locationIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT *` returns only the columns from the table definition.

If you want to get the `rowid` column, you have to list it explicitly:

```sql
SELECT *, rowid FROM ...
```

And if you actually need to use this column, it would be a better idea to make it part of the table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bookmarks (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,    -- same as rowid
    title TEXT,
    ...
)
```